# How does the compiler translate set operations?

Tags: delphi, set

I have the following set operations:

```
program SetOperations;

type
  TMySet = (v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6);

var
  myset: TMySet;
begin
  // Some initialization

  // Operation 1
  if v1 in myset then ;

  // Operation 2
  myset := [v1] + [v2];

  // Operation 3
  myset := myset - [v3];

  // Operation 4
  myset := [v1,v2,v3];
end.
```

All these are normal set operations. I have the following assumptions that I need you to confirm:

1. Operation: The compiler would return true if the first bit of `myset` equals `1`.
2. Operation: The compiler would set the first two bits of `myset` to `1` and the rest to `0`.
3. Operation: The compiler would set the third bit to `0`.
4. Operation: The compiler would set the first three bits to `1` and the rest to `0`.

I'm interested in the internal workings of the Delphi set type.

I would like you to confirm if this is correct and if it is wrong, how is it handled?

Comment: The implementation is not specified anywhere. If you want to see what the compiler does, look at the code that it emits. But yes, it is essentially as you indicate, a bit is allocated for each ordinal value. If it is set, that ordinal is in the set, and vice versa. Generally you would not need to know how the compiler implements sets. Unless you were trying to write some assembler yourself, or some other low level need. It might help if we know what is motivating the question. Or is it just plain curiosity. In which case, study the code under the CPU view of the debugger.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan plain curiosity it is, and the reason is that I don't know a thing about assembler.

Comment: Mot much more to add. Not sure I want to write an answer that says "yes"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sets are stored using a bitplane, e.g. one bit per included ordinal.
A set can only encompass 256 different values. At 1 bit per value, this means a set can take up 32 bytes maximum.
Delphi will try to use the smallest space possible for a set and for performance reasons it is wise to limit the size of a set so it fits inside a CPU register.

Make sure to pass large sets as `const` parameter lest you copy lots of data around.

The operations on sets are implemented using boolean logic.
In the following table `s` is a set and `m` is an ordinal which may or may not be in the set. `b` is a boolean.

```
s:= [m,n]        s:= (1 shl m) or (1 shl n) assignment
s:= s + m        s:= s or (1 shl m)         add 
s:= s - m        s:= s and not(1 shl m)     subtract
s:= s * [m]      s:= s and (1 shl m)        intersection
b:= m in s       b:= (s and (1 shl m)) <> 0 inclusion
b:= s1 >= s2     b:= s1 = (s1 or s2)        subset
b:= s1 <= s2     b:= s2 = (s1 or s2)        subset
b:= s1 <> s2     b:= (s1 xor s2) <> 0
```

As you can see operations with sets (esp. small sets that fit into a CPU register) are incredibly fast and simple.
It is a great shame not more languages have such a cool built-in set type as Pascal does.